# How to fill in another table using a partial match to data in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to fill in a table using data from another table. I've researched the `VLOOKUP` function, and either I don't fully understand it, or it isn't the right tool. 
For example, let's say I have a column of data that is of the format: `(p53, chk2, stra8-cre)`
From this column, I want to extract any row (the entire row) that has 'chk2' in it. What tool can I use for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm understanding, you're trying to have a formula in one cell that sets the content of all cells in its row. As far as I know, you can't do that without some sort of macro.

My suggestion would be to have a similar formula in each of the rows you want to set.

**EDIT:**
Use `SEARCH` to help with this problem. Look [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text) on how to use it for this case.

Ex:

layout in `CSV` format:

`p53chk2,a2,a3
chk2,b2,b3
stra8-cre,c3,c4`

formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("chk2",$A1)),B1,"")`

Copy this formula across all cells in the row, and the contentshould be applied the subsequent cells.

Hope this helps, let me know if this isn't exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit unclear. (p53, chk2, stra8-cre) is the contents of a single cell. There will be other cells like it, but may have different contents (p53, chk1, stra8-cre) is one I wouldn't want to include, but (p21, chk2, hspa2-cre) is one that I would want to include. I think you are correct in that there may be no way to do it without a macro.

Comment: Oh so you're looking for a partial match, where `chk2` is somewhere in an individual cell

Comment: @Yeezy I think my edit will work with what you want to do